# 10.8.2 DNS in hosts lookup slow

Tags: dns, hosts

As a web developer, I need to make a domain redirect to localhost. I modified the hosts file to do that. But I don't know why it always took so long to do the lookup.[image: slow DNS lookup]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using something like mysite.dev in the hosts file.

Further details in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841421/mac-osx-lion-dns-lookup-order).